# Validation of a b:modal form is not working

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am trying to validate a modal form ( JSF/Bootsfaces ) and prevent it from being saved if the inputtext is not correct. For some reason I ignore it is not working, here is the JSF code:

```
    <b:modal id="creation"
             title="#{msgs['page.manageFlights.addingNew']}"
             styleClass="formValidationModalClass"
             closeOnEscape="false"
             backdrop="false"
             closable="false">

        <b:form id="createModal">
            <b:selectOneMenu
                    value="#{flightBean.currentFlight.journey}"
                    label="#{msgs['page.manageFlights.findAllJourneys']}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Please select a journey"
                    large-screen="full-width">
                <f:selectItems value="#{journeyBean.findAllJourneys()}" var="journey" itemValue="#{journey}" itemLabel="#{journey.departureLocation} -> #{journey.arrivalLocation}" />

            </b:selectOneMenu>
            <b:dateTimePicker
                    value="#{flightBean.currentFlight.departureDate}"
                    label="#{msgs['page.manageFlights.departureDate']}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Please enter a date and time"
                    large-screen="full-width">
            </b:dateTimePicker>

            <b:dateTimePicker
                    value="#{flightBean.currentFlight.arrivalDate}"
                    label="#{msgs['page.manageFlights.arrivalDate']}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Please enter a date and time"
                    large-screen="full-width">
            </b:dateTimePicker>

            <b:inputText     value="#{flightBean.currentFlight.numberOfBusinessClassSeats}"
                             label="#{msgs['page.manageFlights.numberOfBusinessClassSeats']}"
                             required="true"
                             requiredMessage="The number of seats must be positive"
                             large-screen="full-width">
                <f:validateLongRange minimum = "1" maximum = "2000" />
            </b:inputText>
            <b:inputText
                    value="#{flightBean.currentFlight.numberOfEconomyClassSeats}"
                    label="#{msgs['page.manageFlights.numberOfEconomyClassSeats']}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Please enter a number"
                    validatorMessage="The number of seats must be positive"
                    large-screen="full-width">
            </b:inputText>
            <br/>
            <b:row>
                <b:column>
                    <b:commandButton
                            largeScreen="half"
                            value="#{msgs['cancel.button']}"
                            dismiss="modal"
                            action="#{flightBean.resetCurrentFlight()}"
                            oncomplete="$('#creation').modal('hide')"
                    />
                    <b:commandButton
                            largeScreen="half"
                            dismiss="modal"
                            update="@(#dataTable)"
                            value="#{msgs['save.button']}" look="success"
                            action="#{flightBean.addFlight(flightBean.currentFlight)}"
                            oncomplete="if(!validationFailed) { $('#creation').modal('hide')};">
                    </b:commandButton>
                </b:column>
            </b:row>
            <b:fetchBeanInfos/>
            <b:messages/>
        </b:form>
    </b:modal>
```

I am trying to check if the number of business class seats is positive.
As you can see I added fetchbeaninfos, validateLongRange and oncomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<b:fetchBeanInfos>` and `validationFailed` only work after an AJAX request. You need to send the input to the server, have it validated there, and only when the response is sent back to the client, `validationFailed` is updated.

My suggestion is to use simple JavaScript to show the error message and to disable the button.

However, if you prefer to use server-side validation, here's what to do:

- Add an empty `validateInput()` method to your bean. It doesn't need any implementation; it just has to be there so it can be called by an JSF AJAX call.
- Add an `id` to `<b:fetchBeanInfos>`.
- Add an AJAX change listener to each input field. Depending on the type of the input field, you may need a different listener (`onblur`, `onchange`, etc.), but the general idea is like so:

  ```
  <b:inputText
              onblur="ajax:flightBean.validateInput()"
              update="**:fetchBeansId"
              value="..."
              label="..."
              required="true"
              requiredMessage="..."
              validatorMessage="...">
  </b:inputText>
  <b:fetchBeanInfos id="fetchBeansId"/>
  ```

The `**:id`bit helps you if your JSF page has multiple "namespaces", such as forms, modals, data tables, and tabs. These namespaces add a prefix to the id, and `**:id` allows you to find the `id` no matter what the prefix is.